# Extract text information(city name) from Image using python

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, tesseract

I have some images and I want to extract some city names from it. Certainly, I can use OpenCV and tesseract for that but the issue is in every image the position of the city name is not static. Is there any way I can do it.

Here are two images

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe add your input image so we can experiment

Comment: Done plz check yourself @nathancy

Comment: You would need some type of definition which describes what a city name looks like. For instance if you know that the city name is highlighted a different color you can use color thresholding but most likely the city is not highlighted. Another way is to OCR then compare each word to a table of cities, if the word is in the table then you have identified a city

Comment: what if all the cities are pre-defined and stored in a db.
In nutshell can I search a known particular word in an image without converting the whole image to text and searching on it?

Comment: not that I know of, you would have to convert the entire image to text then compare it to your db then extract the desired word